# Recommended resolution requires restart when monitor cable is plugged in laptop

Tags: display

I have a Macbook Pro (mid-2015) with Bootcamp and an LG 4K monitor, but whenever I attach the monitor to the laptop using an HDMI cable with the laptop on, I don't get the recommended resolution, receiving 1080p instead.

The recommended resolution is not available in Windows 10's Display Settings, so I have to restart the computer every time to get 4K resolution. Any ideas?